# Bash script unable to communicate with report portal - throws 401

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenoid, reportportal

I am getting following error when executing my automated script through jenkins or running bash command from terminal. I am passing report portal credential in jenkins file and tried to pass in mvn command as well (in .sh file) but no success. Can someone please help me, will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Exception:

com.epam.reportportal.service.launch - [17] report portal execution error retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.httpexception: 401 unauthorized

[image]

Comment: Not related to Selenoid. 401 code means authentication data is missing \ invalid.

Comment: I tried to investigate and resolve but couldn't find the root cause so I thought to put the question here so that someone help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by regenerating the UUID in report portal and used that newly generated id in reportportal.properties file.